# Putting a view to the right of another view in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want textfield3 to be in the left of textfield2.

**app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/txt2"** does not work.
Or I miss something here.

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="TEXTFIELD 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="TEXTFIELD 2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/txt2"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="TEXTFIELD 3"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Considering the screenshot you posted, do you want to move `txt3` to be next to the left edge of `txt2`, or do you want to move `txt2` to be next to the right edge of `txt3`?

Comment: txt3 to be next to the left edge of txt2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my layout is correct, the screenshot i posted is from the layout editor of Android Studio 3.0. But when I run on the emulator, text3 is actually sticking to the left of text2.

It must have been a bug in the layout editor.

Answer (score 2):

In `ConstraintLayout`, each widget must be constrained horizontally and vertically. If they are not, then the result will be off. Some of your `TextView`s are missing constraints. Try something like the following:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="TEXTFIELD 1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="TEXTFIELD 2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txt3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txt3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:text="TEXTFIELD 3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txt1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]